# jQuery if attribute contains a certain value

Tags: jquery

Having a total mind blank here.
Hoping you can help.

How would I alter this argument to be when the attribute 'href does not start with #overlay'...

```
if(this.getTrigger().attr("href")){
// stuff in here
}
```

Thanks you wonderful people.
Kevin

Comment: I think you should accept Andy E's answer. It's the most correct/complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery selectors:

```
if(this.getTrigger().is('a:not([href^="#overlay]")')) {
  // stuff in here
}
```

**Edit**: In your case where you already have only one item and want to check its `href` value, the selector solution performs worse than just comparing a slice of the attribute to `'#overlay'` as the other answers here have shown. I just posted my solution to show there is more than one way to do it.

Comment: @Kevin: with no disrespect intended towards @chiborg, I'd strongly urge you to rethink your approach. `is()` is very poor performance compared to standard string comparison methods. Think about it this way, jQuery has to parse each part of the selector string and run many conditional checks before reaching the conclusion. All of the other answers here with outperform this solution greatly.

Comment: @Andy E: No disrespect done :) I have updated my text to clarify that my solution is suboptimal for this particular use case.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) or [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```
if (this.getTrigger().attr("href").slice(0, 8) != "#overlay") {
}
```

or [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
if (this.getTrigger().attr("href").indexOf("#overlay") != 0) {
}
```

or the regex [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method:

```js
if (!/^#overlay/.test(this.getTrigger().attr("href"))) {
}
```

Comment: `substring` is the fastest (when considering both failed and successful searches): http://jsperf.com/js-startswith/6

Comment: @galambalazs: thanks - I went with the `slice`/`substring` methods first because I knew they were faster than string searching, but it's nice to have something concrete to show that.

Answer (score 1):

You could check this way

```
if(this.getTrigger().attr("href").indexOf('#overlay') != 0) {
}
```

Comment: I believe that should be:
indexOf('#overlay') != -1

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf()`:

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://company.com/?action=someAction">someAction</a>

href = $("#myLink").attr('href');

if(href.toLowerCase().indexOf('someaction') >= 0) {
    alert("someAction was found on href");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `match(RegEx)` to test if href starts with `#overlay` then negate it:

```
if (!this.getTrigger().attr("href").match(/^#overlay/)) {
    // stuff in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(str){
    return (this.indexOf(str) === 0);
}

if(!this.getTrigger().attr("href").startsWith("#overlay")){
// stuff in here
}
```

Or

```
var check = "#overlay";
if(!this.getTrigger().attr("href").substring(0, check.length) === check){
// stuff in here
}
```